# How to set watcher to get know if a particular mutation was called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I use ApolloClient. Need to get know if the mutation was called. Is there a watcher in GraphQL or hook that can take the name of the mutation and as a result return the result of the mutation or say with what variables it was called, or if it was simply called?
The purpose isn't just to know if it was called (in browser devtools or etc) - I need to use that information to writhe frontend logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to track if a mutation/query is called is via the browser network tab. You'll be able to see all of the network requests with the parameters that were sent. In browser developer tools -> network tab.

Click on the Fetch/XRH filter as well to limit the results.

If there is an action that you want to do after the mutation is called, onCompleted will be your best bet.

```
const [muationHere] = useMutation(
 MUTATION,
   {
      onCompleted(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
   }
 );
```

Comment: please check my question editing

Comment: @Gedrimas I edited my answer. If all you need to know is if it was called or not Daniel's answer will work. If you need to perform an action after the mutation is completed see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo already gives you the API for it: `called`

See example:

```
const [login, { data, loading, error, called }] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION);
```

if you just want to see the request you can see it in the dev tools under network

Comment: I think "called" only works with useLazyQuery right? If not let me know!

Comment: Works with useMutation too :)

Comment: please check my question editing